# How to reprogram the Dell TrackStick buttons?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, hotkeys, dell-latitude

I don't use the TrackStick on my new Dell Laptop.
I would love to reprogram the 3 buttons to use for other purposes.
Is there anyway to do that?
[image]

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 10